# no popup for android webview to upload files or open camera

Tags: android, react-native, webview, popup

I couldn't get popup for my android webview app, I have tried everything possible could someone help me please, here is my mainActivity code.

What I am trying to do is to load my webview which I get successfully but there is a personal page where if a user click on profile picture it should prompt either to open camera or load image from galler and again there is an upload option if pressed same thing should happen either to upload photos or open camera, Its working fine if I do it from my browser but not from my webview android app

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private static final int MY_BLINK_ID_REQUEST_CODE = 0x101;
public static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 101;
private static final int REQUEST_WEBFORM = 300;
public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessageLP;
private Uri directUploadImageUri;


private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupToolbar();

    loadHtml();
}




public void cancelFileUpload() {
    if (mUploadMessage != null) {
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }

    if (uploadMessageLP != null) {
        uploadMessageLP.onReceiveValue(null);
        uploadMessageLP = null;
    }

    this.directUploadImageUri = null;
}



public void setUploadMessageLP(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessageLP) {
    this.uploadMessageLP = uploadMessageLP;
}





/**
 * setup toolbar
 */
private void setupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //change title color
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
    //set title
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

}

private void loadHtml() {
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    // Render the HTML file on WebView
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://new.techyardnepal.com");

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_favorite) {
        startOCRScan();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * start ocr on scan id click
 */
private void startOCRScan() {
    // Intent for MyScanActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MRPScanActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, MY_BLINK_ID_REQUEST_CODE);

}

/**
 * This method is called whenever control is returned from activity started with
 * startActivityForResult.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // onActivityResult is called whenever we are returned from activity started
    // with startActivityForResult. We need to check request code to determine
    // that we have really returned from BlinkID activity.
    if (requestCode == MY_BLINK_ID_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == MRPScanActivity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            // depending on settings, we may have multiple scan results.
            // we first need to obtain recognition results
            RecognitionResults results = data.getParcelableExtra(ScanActivity.EXTRAS_RECOGNITION_RESULTS);
            BaseRecognitionResult[] resArray = null;
            if (results != null) {
                // get array of recognition results
                resArray = results.getRecognitionResults();
            }
            if (resArray != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Data count: " + resArray.length);
                int i = 1;

                for (BaseRecognitionResult res : resArray) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data #" + Integer.valueOf(i++).toString());

                    // Each element in resultArray inherits BaseRecognitionResult class and
                    // represents the scan result of one of activated recognizers that have
                    // been set up.

                    res.log();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to retrieve recognition data!");
            }

            data.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, ResultActivity.class));
            startActivity(data);
        }
    }
    if (data != null && data.getBooleanExtra("exit", false))
        finish();





    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            cancelFileUpload();
            return;
        }

        // from documents (and video camera)
        if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(data.getData());
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }


            return;
        }

        // we may get clip data for multi-select documents
        if (data != null && data.getClipData() != null) {
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<>(clipData.getItemCount());
            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                if (item.getUri() != null) {
                    files.add(item.getUri());
                }
            }

            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                // shouldn never happen, but just in case, send the first item
                if (files.size() > 0) {
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(files.get(0));
                } else {
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }

            if (uploadMessageLP != null) {
                uploadMessageLP.onReceiveValue(files.toArray(new Uri[files.size()]));
                uploadMessageLP = null;
            }

            return;
        }

        // from camera
        if (this.directUploadImageUri != null) {
            // check if we have external storage permissions
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                // wait for the onRequestPermissionsResult callback
                return;
            }


            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(this.directUploadImageUri);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
            if (uploadMessageLP != null) {
                uploadMessageLP.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{this.directUploadImageUri});
                uploadMessageLP = null;
            }
            this.directUploadImageUri = null;

            return;
        }

        // Should not reach here.
        cancelFileUpload();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ty changing setWebViewClient to setWebChromeClient

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout mLayout;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private WebView webView;
String loadUrl;

private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private WebSettings webSettings;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;
ValueCallback<Uri[]> chooserPathUri;

public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

WebView chooserWV;
WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams chooserParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadUrl = "https:google.com";

    mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl(loadUrl); //change with your website

    this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return handleUrl(url);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            return handleUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        }
    });
}

public boolean handleUrl(String url){

    if (url.startsWith("geo:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:")) {
        Intent searchAddress = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(searchAddress);
    }else
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int permissionCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int permissionStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (permissionCamera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        Log.e(TAG, "Returned falseeeee-------");
        return false;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Permission returned trueeeee-------");
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Permission callback called-------");
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
            // Initialize the map with both permissions
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with actual results from user
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for both permissions
                if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "camera & Storage permission granted");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted! Try now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //chromClt.openChooser(chooserWV, chooserPathUri, chooserParams);
                    // process the normal flow
                    //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                    //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
                    // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                    //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        showDialogOK("Camera and Storage Permission required for this app",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        switch (which) {
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                break;
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                    //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}

private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        Uri[] results = null;
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                            final int numSelectedFiles = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                            results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];

                            for (int i = 0; i < numSelectedFiles; i++) {
                                results[i] = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    return;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}

public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
        Log.e(TAG, "onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt: " );
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }

    // For Android 5.0
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

        chooserWV = view;
        chooserPathUri = filePath;
        chooserParams = fileChooserParams;

        if(checkAndRequestPermissions()){
            openChooser(chooserWV, chooserPathUri, chooserParams);

            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }


    public void openChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){

        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;
        Intent takePictureIntent;

        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        }
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
        File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                , "AndroidExampleFolder");
        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        // Create camera captured image file path and name
        File file = new File(
                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg");
        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
        // Camera capture image intent
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        // Create file chooser intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
        // Set camera intent to file chooser
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});
        // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity

        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                String acceptType,
                                String capture) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }

}



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.onResume();
    // ...
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    webView.onPause();
    // ...
    super.onPause();
}

int mExit = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

**Don't forget to add permissions in Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```